# Two identical objects circling the center of mass periodically in general relativity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity

In Newton's gravity we can have two identical objects circle the center of mass periodically (assuming the surroundings are vacuum).

Is something like this possible in general relativity? Is there an exact solution available?

Comment: Sure, although "center of mass" isn't always well-defined.  But you can have the two objects being in symmetric positions.  For example, light on the event horizon of a black hole.  I suppose a proper answer will depend on how physical you want your GR argument to be, i.e. are you imagining a pure neo-classical textbook interpretation of GR, or something less classical?

Comment: Using light feels a little like a cheatcode. Can the objects be massive? Unfortunately I don't know anything about interpretations.

Comment: Now that I think of it they will probably have to collapse because they will emit waves and so energy will be running away to infinity? Basically what people expected electrons to do when circling the nucleus (and what was later fixed with quantization).

Comment: Another example would be a Lorentz torus, i.e. $\mathbb R \times (S^1)^3$ where you give it a product Lorentz metric.  I think you could take any two "not too big" masses, provided they are symmetrically separated.  Of course this kind of plays games with your "orbiting periodically" condition, since the space is now periodic -- viewing them as "orbiting" or as "stationary" is a matter of perspective.

Comment: Oh I want the spacetime to be an open submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (with the standard smooth structure)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity